# creating tablespace failed!

Tags: oracle-11g

I've restored a db and its failed with many errors. When I look into the log file, I found that the tablespace does not exist. So when I try to create a tablespace in plsql am getting the following error!

[image]

Comment: Did you read the error message? It says your diskgroup is full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake that I did not check the disk available space.

```
select a.FREE_MB,a.* from V$ASM_DISKGROUP a
```

It was only 8gb available. That's why the query ran out of error.

I'm sorry for my mistake. And thanks everyone for their time and consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Login to ASM

run the following command to reblance the disk-group in the server

```
alter diskgroup PROD_DATA  rebalance power 5;
```

then check the ASM operation

```
select * from v$asm_operation;
```

after that re-create the tablespace